# Using Super Class and Extend From It

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, abstract, superclass

I want to sort some team base on their points (win: 3 points, draw: 1 points and defeat: 0 points). I have an array which contains some teams' names and their results, I have extracted their scores and then sorted them descending. Here is the code I have used:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class SCAN{
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> points = new HashMap<>();
        String[] challenges = new String[]{
            "Team(A) 2 - 1 Team(C)",
            "Team(D) 3 - 1 Team(A)",
            "Team(B) 3 - 3 Team(D)",
            "Team(C) 0 - 4 Team(B)",
            "Team(B) 2 - 0 Team(A)"
        };
    calcualte(challenges, points);
    List<Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(
            points.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>() {
        public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> e1,
                Entry<String, Integer> e2) {
            return e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue()); // Sorts
                                                            // descending.
        }
    });
    Map<String, Integer> orderedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : entries) {
        orderedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    for (Entry<String, Integer> element : entries) {
        System.out.println(element);
        }
}

private static void calcualte(String[] challenges, Map<String, Integer> points) {
    List<String> challengeList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String str : challenges) {
        String[] bits = str.trim().split(" ");
        String firstTeam = bits[0];
        String lastTeam = bits[bits.length - 1];
        if (!challengeList.contains(firstTeam)) {
            challengeList.add(firstTeam);
        }
        if (!challengeList.contains(lastTeam)) {
            challengeList.add(lastTeam);
        }
        int firstScore = Integer.parseInt(bits[1]);
        int lastScore = Integer.parseInt(bits[3]);
        if (firstScore > lastScore) {
            insert(3, points, firstTeam);
            insert(0, points, lastTeam);
        } else if (firstScore < lastScore) {
            insert(3, points, lastTeam);
            insert(0, points, firstTeam);
        } else {
            insert(1, points, firstTeam);
            insert(1, points, lastTeam);
        }
        {

        }
    }

}

private static void insert(int i, Map<String, Integer> points, String team) {
    int score = points.containsKey(team) ? points.get(team) : 0;
    score += i;
    points.put(team, score);
}
}
```

I know this, but I should do it by using a superclass So I need a subclass which its name is `Plays` and should be extended from a super class which its name is `Playclass` . The `Playclass` should not be changed. This class needs three abstracted method which should be overridden, they are `won()`,`drawn()` and `defeated()`. The other method which should to be overridden, is `Print()` which shows each team's information, like bellow:

```
public abstract class Playclass {
    private String name;
    Playclass(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public abstract void print();
    public abstract void won();
    public abstract void drawn();
    public abstract void defeated();

}
```

The main class name could be `Playleage` and it should contain the  `String[] challenges = new String[]{…}`  which I showed in the first code. I know how to sort them base on their scores (like the first code) but I don’t know how to use the classes which I said. May someone help me? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your question. Try breaking it down to an abstract problem with less code. For what it's worth, I get the sense you are confusing subclassing a class and instantiating a class.

Comment: in my eyes, your code already has some problems. for example, you calculate the values in: calcualte(challenges, points); But you do not assign the values to anything. Neither to a global variable, nor is there any return...

Comment: You can ignore the first code and only use the array and then sort every team base on its score by using that classes, the array is  String[] challenges = new String[]{
            "Team(A) 2 - 1 Team(C)",
            "Team(D) 3 - 1 Team(A)",
            "Team(B) 3 - 3 Team(D)",
            "Team(C) 0 - 4 Team(B)",
            "Team(B) 2 - 0 Team(A)"
        };